# Nginx serving Django in subdirectory - admin login is redirecting

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin

I have to serve a Django app from a subdirectory (hostname/*service*/). So far I'm able to get to the Admin Login prompt (hostname/service/admin/login/?next=/admin/), but after successfully logging in I'm redirected to (hostname/admin/login/) and get a 404.
How can I keep the correct subdirectory and get inside the Admin panel?

Here's the nginx.conf server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    charset utf-8;

    location /service {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://djangoapp:8000/;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }
}
```

Edit: These are the urlpatterns from urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

# A custom view of my own
from app.views import AdvanceCustomSearchView

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^search/$', AdvanceCustomSearchView(), name='index_search'),
  url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: please, update with your URL patterns, available in the urls.py file that's in the same folder with settings.py

Comment: @fixmycode Updated with URL patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the [`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name) setting to your `settings.py` as such:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/service'
```

mind that there's no trailing slash at the end.